# Efficient algorithm to find a symmetric matrix that commute with a given set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

Given a set of $K$ real $n \times n$ matrices $\{B_k\}$, what's the most efficient way to find a symmetric matrix $X$ that commute with all of $\{B_k\}$, i.e.,

$[X,B_k] = XB_k - B_kX = 0 \quad \forall \; k=1,\dots, K.$

The matrix $X$ needs to be a *generic* solution in the sense that it has no unnecessary eigenvalue degeneracy (e.g., identity matrix $I_n$ is always a solution but not a generic one).

I can map this problem to an eigenvector problem of $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix and solve it with method of $\mathcal{O}(n^4)$ complexity. But I wonder whether more efficient algorithms exist. Approximate solutions with $[X,B_k] < \epsilon$ are acceptable and any practical methods with high success rate are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the setup really is. Do you know a priori that an exact non-trivial solution exists? If you want just an approximate solution, how generic should it be? (I can always take a small perturbation of the identity and declare that it has "no eigenvalue degeneracy"). Probably, rather than trying to squeeze a well-posed problem from you, I'll just ask what you are going to do with your $X$ afterwards. That should clarify a few things I'm rather uneasy about in the current formulation.

Comment: @fedja I would like to simultaneously block diagonalize $\{B_k\}$, which can be done by an orthogonal matrix $P$ that diagonalize any of the generic solution $X$. If no non-trivial solution exists, then the algorithm should find the identity matrix.

Comment: OK, it makes much more sense now. And what is the typical value of $n$?

Comment: @fedja can be anything. Current O(4) algorithm can handle up to a few hundred

Comment: At this point I start wondering about something: if you have an $n^2\times n^2$ matrix, a single multiplication by a vector takes $n^4$ operations already and the inversion of the matrix takes $n^6$. Just multiplying two $n\times n$ matrices ($n^3$ operations) gets frustratingly slow on my PC for $n=500$, and you are presumably successfully finding bottom eigenvectors of $n^2\times n^2$, which requires way more time. What am I missing?

Comment: @fedja matrix-vector multiplications for an $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix takes $\mathcal{O}(n^4)$, and that is what it takes to find the smallest eigenvalue/eigenvector through Lanczos algorithm. (Please correct me if this is wrong, as I am aware that the worst case analysis of Lanczos algorithm is very tricky.)

Comment: Well, if you are talking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_algorithm , then you allow yourself just a constant number of iterations so I'm a bit suspicious. Of course, you can get the corresponding mapping on the space symmetric matrices by multiplying matrices instead and then you have your matrix-vector multiplication in $Kn^3$ operations instead of $n^4$, so you can afford $n$ iterations after that, which sufficed in my experiments with the eigenvector idea, so I can also do the size of like 300 so far. But if you meant something more interesting, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how well this will work, but have you tried the following? (I'll be talking about the simultaneous block-diagonalization problem immediately). Note that if the matrices $B_j$ are simultaneously block-diagonalizable, then, for any linear combination $B=\sum_j \xi_j B_j$, the top eigenvector of $B$ is lying in one of the blocks. So, start with taking a random linear combination $B$ and finding the top eigenvector $v$ by some fast method (see something like [this](http://www.cs.unc.edu/techreports/96-043.pdf) though I surmise you know such stuff better than I do). That is (almost and on average) $O(Kn^2)$ (at least it is as much $O(Kn^2)$ and your $O(n^4)$ is really $O(n^4)$. Now notice that that block should be (nearly, if you are fine with an approximate diagonalization) closed under the action of all $B^j$ and $B_j^T$. So, start running Gram-Schmidt on $v_1=v$, $B_j v, B_j^Tv$ ignoring the vectors that test almost linearly dependent with the previous ones. The orthogonalization itself is fast until the block grows really large and even then it is just $n^2$ per vector, so I'll not even count it. The real quadratic cost comes from finding the images. Now assume that you obtained $s$ vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_s$ in those $2Kn^2$ steps. Mix them into a random combination (Gaussian randomness is the best, as usual) and try to see if every image of that combination is (nearly) in the span of $v_1,\dots,v_s$ under $B_j$ and $B_j^T$ (sam G-S). If it is, declare a complete block (you may want to test 2-5 combinations to be more sure). If not, expand the system accordingly and repeat. Every time your cost is $2Kn^2$ and you increase the dimension of the block by at least $1$.

Suppose you have a chunk of your basis now and you know that it is (nearly) invariant. Replace your operators by $(I-P)B_j(I-P)$ where $P$ is the projection to the chunk (only do not multiply matrices but operate on vectors instead when iterating for eigenvalues) and repeat. You'll get a second block and so on. The total cost of constructing the basis is $O(Kn^3)$. Since the cost of the single final rotation of the operators to the basis is $Kn^3$ (unless you use really fancy matrix multiplication schemes, but they become effective only in the range of thousands), so you can hardly do better.  The final check that the rotation worked is about $Kn^2$, which is nothing again.

Does that make sense to you? If it does, try it and let me know what happens.

Comment: @Yuanzhao On the second thought, this should work decently if you have *exact* block diagonalization, but not as good if you have only an approximate one. In the latter case it may be a good idea to invest into the full eigenvalue/eigenvector search for a random self-adjoint matrix $B=\sum_j[\xi_j(B_j+Bj^*)+i\eta_j(B_j-B_j^*)]$ with Gaussian $\xi$,$\eta$ (notice that every self-adjoint $X$ that truly commutes with $B$ is a function of $B$ with probability $1$ in the ideal block-diagonalizability case, so all we'll need afterwards is to link some eigenvectors of $B$ together into one subspace

Comment: @Yuanzhao However, in the approximate diagonalizable case some more work may be needed. How good is the block separation you are thinking of in reality? Also, the suggestion above gives a unitary rotation instead of an orthogonal one. Do you care much about whether to work over $\mathbb R$ or over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @Yuanzhao Finally, what is the value of $K$ compared to $n$. Is it much smaller, much larger, or of comparable size?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. $K$ is typically much smaller than $n$. Working over $\mathbb{C}$ is fine. We can focus on exact block diagonalization for now if it makes things easier.

Comment: I can't say I fully understand the answer. Are you suggesting to start with an eigenvector of $B$, then multiply it with $B_j$ and $B_j^T$ until no linearly independent vectors can be produced and call the resulting $v_1, \dots, v_s$ a block (invariant space)?

Comment: @Yuanzhao Pretty much. You can also use some other matrix that has the same block structure. For instance, $\sum_j (B_j^TB_j+B_j B_j^T)$. Note that it may go sour if the block diagonalization is only approximate, but if it is exact, it will work. I'll try to experiment with it a bit and see if I can upgrade it, but I would really appreciate if you could answer my stupid questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another perspective:

What you're really doing is solving a system of [Sylvester equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).  In particular, you're looking for the nullspace of the $(n^2 K) \times n^2$ matrix given by
$$
\pmatrix{I \otimes B_1 - B_1^T \otimes I
\\
I \otimes B_2 - B_2^T \otimes I\\
\vdots\\
I \otimes B_K - B_K^T \otimes I}
$$
With the further constraint that $X^T = X$. You might be able to reduce that down a bit using [half-vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Half-vectorization) in some way.  There are plenty of linear systems algorithms around.  That being said, I'm not convinced any of them beat $O(n^4)$ in this case.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ must map the generalized eigenspaces of each $B_k$ into themselves.  That is, if $(B_k - \lambda)^m v = 0$ then $(B_k - \lambda)^m Xv = 0$.  Depending on the structure of these eigenspaces, that can be a very helpful constraint.